# Throw bad_alloc if there's not enough memory

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

```
/ *
* \ brief Dictionary builder from file
*
* \ pre There is enough memory
* \ pre The file is first opened
*
* \ post If the file is open, the class instance has been initialized from
* from the dictionary file. Otherwise, we generate an empty class.
*
* \ exception bad_alloc if there is not enough memory
* This method calls chargeDicSyn!
* /
DicSyn::DicSyn(std::ifstream &file):
root(0), nbRadicals(0), groupesSynonymes()
{
    chargeDicSyn(file);
}
```

I have to throw the exception `bad_alloc` if there's not enough memory. I am really not an expert. How can I do it with this method?

Comment: What do the function `chargeDicSyn` and the constructors of `root`, `nbRadicals` and `groupesSynonymes` do?

Comment: Throw it like any other exception? But generally, doesn't `new` and `new[]` already do so if there's "not enough memory"? What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: @RayHamel I had a little description of over the method definition

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code that directly allocated any heap memory.  So the above code can not directly run out of heap.  Please post a [mcve] ie some code that does directly allocate memory and as @RayHamel said `operator new` does this by default.

Comment: *exception bad_alloc if there is not enough memory* -- If there is not enough to do what exactly?  That comment lacks information on what exactly is allocating memory.  Even then we need to see the code that actually allocates memory.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is using `operator new` (or anything that uses `operator new`, such as the standard library) to allocate memory, then it should *already* throw `std::bad_alloc` if there is not enough memory.

Edit: If it's using C-style memory management (`malloc` and friends), which I don't think it is, since you're constructing your object from a `std::ifstream` and not a `FILE*` like in C, then you should check if `malloc` returned `nullptr` (i.e. the pointer to which the call to `malloc` was assigned is null) and throw `std::bad_alloc` if it did. If for some reason you aren't able to do that, you could `#include <cerrno>` and check if `errno == ENOMEM`, although this is not quite as foolproof since `malloc` is not guaranteed to set `errno` on failure.